# Calling git commands from sub directory

Tags: git

What actually happens when I call git commands in a subdirectory within a git repo?

For example, I invoked `git init` in `~/repo_root`, but some time later I ran `git commit` from `~/repo_root/subdir1`

Comment: You may wish to clarify whether `~/repo` and `~/repo_root` are actually intended to be the same, or different.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Git commands work fine when executed from a subdirectory of your repository. The only difference is that arguments which refer to files are taken as relative to the current working directory.

In your example, `git commit` would have worked fine because Git searches up the directory  hierarchy to find the `.git` repository directory.

Comment: Note that he is running `git commit` from a *sibling* directory, *not* a sub directory, `~/repo` vs `~/repo_root`. I assume this probably a typo, but...

Comment: I saw that, and asked for clarification. The text of the question says *subdirectory*.

Comment: Typo in the directory name. Mistake fixed!